# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' when working on FirebaseAuth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-services

I am doing Firebase Auth Application in Android and i geting in trubble(stuck).I got this error *Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'*

I added these dependancies in gradle.build in(Module:app)

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
// compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I also Added classpath in gradle.build project

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Added **google-services.json** file in android Project

I also Checked 
   1)**AndroidManifests** file package name,
   2)In **gradle.app** applicationId and
   3) In **google-services.json** package_name.
 Everywhere name are Same.

I don't know where actually getting problem

Comment: Often when that error occurs, there is additional text displayed, such as ""Please fix the version conflict...".  Does your error message include more text?

Comment: i will show you error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Missing api_key/current_key object

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I got Answer for this question....
Sorry i forgot place *api_key*